# UIAlertView Problems

Tags: swift, uitableview, uialertview, xcode8, ios10

I started having this problem since I updated to Xcode 8 I do not know if it could depend on precisely an Xcode bug.

I have this problem: [this happens when I add this view to a tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs9iF.png).

It should be so [if you do not tie it to anything it remains unchanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weF9M.png).

The problems is not my code 
I add below

```
import UIKit
```

class PhotoSelectViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var selectImageButton: UIButton!

weak var delegate: PhotoSelectViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func selectImageTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Choose image source", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default) { (_) in
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (_) in
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        actionSheet.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
    }
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        actionSheet.addAction(cameraAction)
    }

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    selectImageButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.image = image
        delegate?.photoSelectViewControllerSelectedImage(image: image)
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

protocol PhotoSelectViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func photoSelectViewControllerSelectedImage(image: UIImage)
}

Comment: try to give it a default width

Comment: Could you please show how you are added alert ?

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8.

Now you need to use UIAlertController:

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose image source", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { result in
        print("Destructive")
    }

    // Replace UIAlertActionStyle.Default by UIAlertActionStyle.default
    let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default) { result in
        print("OK")
    }

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
```

[image]

Comment: It is deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: Upvoted. You could make this slightly nicer to read using trailing closures and type inference. I updated your answer if you dont mind.

Comment: Also your properties should start with small letters

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
On iOS 8, you can do as bellow

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```